# function to display dates as YYYY-MMM

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions, date-formatting, scalar

as the title states, I'm trying to make a little function to take date values already in the database and display them as YYYY-MMM (eg: 2013-Nov). SQL Server. I tried DatePart but it only takes one part arguement at a time (cant do YYYY-MMM). Any suggestions **keeping it as a function**?

```
Create function fnYearMonth
(@InputDate date)
returns date
Begin
Return DatePart(YYYY-MMM, @inputdate)
End;

Select hiredate, dbo.fnYearMonth(hiredate) as ReviewDate
from employees
Order by ReviewDate
```

Comment: `returns date` will have to change to make this work - a date is a date is a date. It doesn't *have* a format. It just stores some internal representation of how many days have occurred since some particular epoch date.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use [DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx)

```
DECLARE @InputDate datetime
SELECT @InputDate = '2013-10-10 10:10:10'

DECLARE @output nvarchar(8);
SELECT @output = CAST(DatePart(YYYY, @InputDate) as nvarchar(4)) + '-' + CONVERT(nvarchar(3), datename(month, @InputDate))
SELECT @output;
```

result:

> 2013-Oct

edit:

```
Create function fnYearMonth
(@InputDate date)
returns nvarchar(8)
Begin
Return CAST(DatePart(YYYY, @InputDate) as nvarchar(4)) + '-' + CONVERT(nvarchar(3), datename(month, @InputDate))
End;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DATENAME](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function:

```
Create function fnYearMonth
(@InputDate date)
returns VARCHAR(16)
Begin
Return CAST(YEAR(@InputDate) AS CHAR(4)) + ' '+ DATENAME ( month , @InputDate )
End;
```

Or

```
 CAST(YEAR(@InputDate) AS CHAR(4)) + ' '+ LEFT(DATENAME ( MONTH , @InputDate ),3)
```

if you do not need the whole name of the month.